Regenerate ACR access key using Rest API received Unauthorized
The issue is we cannot regenerate ACR access key using ACR rest API
Registries - Regenerate Credential - REST API (Azure Container Registry) | Microsoft Learn
Throwing exception Microsoft.Azure.Deployment.Express.Server.Common.Management.AzureResourceManagementException: Failed to regenerate Password: 'password'. HttpStatusCode 'Forbidden', Reason phrase:'Forbidden' and Content:'{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' with object id 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/regenerateCredential/action' over scope '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/xxxxxxxxxxxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}'
Expect to not receive the unauthorized issue

as stated in the error message, you're missing some permissions. you should grant contributor role to the user / service principal calling the REST endpoint over the container registry


Regenerate ACR access key using Rest API received Unauthorized

The error you encountered is due to invalid permissions. To regenerate an ACR access key, you may need one of the following roles to perform that action.

REST API  details
In my case, I have the Owner role at the subscription level.

Response:

After executing the REST API, the ACR password was successfully regenerated.

Reference: Registries - Regenerate Credential
